# css question, position div at bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I have below style to position a div to always stay at bottom of the page:

```
.bottom { background-color:#3B5998;
          height:50px;
          margin-left:0px;
          margin-bottom:0px;
          margin-right:0px }

html, body { margin:0px;
             padding:0px; }
```

It is working on one page but not a second page!

Answer (score 2):

You must write the code like this:

```
.bottom {
    background-color:#3B5998;
    height:50px;
    bottom: 0;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;

}

html, body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

See the Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/YEsq8/

Answer (score 1):

You're also forgetting some basics for .bottom:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good tool for ensuring the footer div always 'sticks' to the bottom of the page:

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Answer (score 0):

Add `height:100%` and `min-height:100%` to your class for `html` and `body`.

I still wonder how it worked on one page though, because I think you need some sort of absolute positioning. But give my suggestion a try and see whether it works. If not, please add your HTML code so I can reproduce your issue.